# submit data from Database to Soap service using SSIS

Tags: soap, ssis, data-integration

I want to submit data from database to SOAP web service -already implemented-. I just want to consume it to submit data on it. I don't know what's the best way to do it. I tried to use SSIS and successfully called the service using static data, but my issue here is how to pass it's values to the service complex object using data records from my SQL Server DB.